# Adjective 'winged'

Tags: definite-article

There's a winged boy:

1. The wings are big
2. Wings are big

What is correct if the meaning of 'winged' is the meaning of 'wingses' in 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the adjective "winged" here means the boy as wings, simple enough.

Since we are talking about this specific "winged boy", we say "The wings are big".

When you say "Wings are big", you're saying "*All* wings are big", which is too general. By adding "the", you're talking about a person/thing that was previously mentioned, which in this case is the "winged boy".

Comment: You mean the word mentioned don't need to be noun?

Comment: "Wing" is a singular noun. "Wings" is the plural noun. "Winged" is an adjective. If you say "The *wings* are big", the boy can be small but his wings are big. If you say "The *winged* are big", you're say "People with wings are big", as "the winged" can mean "people with wings". Does that answer your question?

Comment: I mean the is used when a word is already mentioned and the word already mentioned can be adjective or something. I thought the word already mentioned had to be noun, not adjective like 'winged.'

Comment: Give me some conclusion.

Comment: In the first sentence, "the winged boy" is mentioned. In the 2nd sentence, when we say "The wings are big", we're talking about the wings of the boy from sentence 1 "There's a winged boy". "Winged" is an adjective, "(the) wings" is a noun. "Wing" doesn't have to be a noun or adjective in *both* sentences. We just need to mention some "wings" in the first sentence to use "the wings" in the 2nd sentence.